# angularjs set and get radio button values based on json property

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Every answer has a correct property which has a value either true or false. If an option has true value in the correct property I want to set 1 as ng-value and for every false value I want to set ng-value to "-0.5". When someone click the correct answer the score variable will increase by 1 and for a wrong answer score will decrease by 0.5. But it's not working. Please help.

```
var set = 
[
        { 
        "qus" :"what is your name?",
        "option1" : {"ans" : "Alex", "correct":"false"},
        "option2" : {"ans" : "Hervy", "correct":"false"},
        "option3" : {"ans" : "Rico", "correct":"true"},
        "option4" : {"ans" : "Tom", "correct":"false"},
        },

        { 
        "qus" :"what is your brother's name?",
        "option1" : {"ans" : "Alex", "correct":"false"},
        "option2" : {"ans" : "Hervy", "correct":"true"},
        "option3" : {"ans" : "Rico", "correct":"false"},
        "option4" : {"ans" : "Tom", "correct":"false"},
        }   
]
```

Here is the plnkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/9dfSaeDgGU2l5eajm5VZ?p=preview

Comment: more practical way would be pass the whole object back to controller in a change handler

Comment: How to do that. Would you mind to explain?

Comment: `ng-change="update(qs.option1)"` ..then play with that object for calcs